# java.lang.NullPointerException - Can't find the null variable

Tags: java, exception, pointers, null

I hate to ask such a question, but I'm new to java programming... Like, as of yesterday.
I'm trying to splice together a server and a GUI, but am having this issue.
Sorry for the simple question again.

```
    * Copyright (c) 1995, 2008, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.*;



/*
 * The chat client thread. This client thread opens the input and the output
 * streams for a particular client, ask the client's name, informs all the
 * clients connected to the server about the fact that a new client has joined
 * the chat room, and as long as it receive data, echos that data back to all
 * other clients. The thread broadcast the incoming messages to all clients and
 * routes the private message to the particular client. When a client leaves the
 * chat room this thread informs also all the clients about that and terminates.
 */
class clientThread extends Thread {

  private String clientName = null;
  private DataInputStream is = null;
  private PrintStream os = null;
  private Socket clientSocket = null;
  private final clientThread[] threads;
  private int maxClientsCount;

  public clientThread(Socket clientSocket, clientThread[] threads) {
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    this.threads = threads;
    maxClientsCount = threads.length;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void run() {
    int maxClientsCount = this.maxClientsCount;
    clientThread[] threads = this.threads;

    try {
      /*
       * Create input and output streams for this client.
       */
      is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
      os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
      String name;
      while (true) {
        os.println("Enter your name.");
        name = is.readLine().trim();
        if (name.indexOf('@') == -1) {
          break;
        } else {
          os.println("The name should not contain '@' character.");
        }
      }

      /* Welcome the new the client. */
      os.println("Welcome " + name
          + " to our chat room.\nTo leave enter /quit in a new line.");
      synchronized (this) {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
          if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] == this) {
            clientName = "@" + name;
            break;
          }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
          if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] != this) {
            threads[i].os.println("*** A new user " + name
                + " entered the chat room !!! ***");
          }
        }
      }
      /* Start the conversation. */
      while (true) {
        String line = is.readLine();
        if (line.startsWith("/quit")) {
          break;
        }
        /* If the message is private sent it to the given client. */
        if (line.startsWith("@")) {
          String[] words = line.split("\\s", 2);
          if (words.length > 1 && words[1] != null) {
            words[1] = words[1].trim();
            if (!words[1].isEmpty()) {
              synchronized (this) {
                for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
                  if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] != this
                      && threads[i].clientName != null
                      && threads[i].clientName.equals(words[0])) {
                    threads[i].os.println("<" + name + "> " + words[1]);
                    /*
                     * Echo this message to let the client know the private
                     * message was sent.
                     */
                    this.os.println(">" + name + "> " + words[1]);
                    break;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          /* The message is public, broadcast it to all other clients. */
          synchronized (this) {
            for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
              if (threads[i] != null && threads[i].clientName != null) {
                threads[i].os.println("<" + name + "> " + line);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      synchronized (this) {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
          if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] != this
              && threads[i].clientName != null) {
            threads[i].os.println("*** The user " + name
                + " is leaving the chat room !!! ***");
          }
        }
      }
      os.println("*** Bye " + name + " ***");

      /*
       * Clean up. Set the current thread variable to null so that a new client
       * could be accepted by the server.
       */
      synchronized (this) {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
          if (threads[i] == this) {
            threads[i] = null;
          }
        }
      }
      /*
       * Close the output stream, close the input stream, close the socket.
       */
      is.close();
      os.close();
      clientSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
  }
}

/*
 * A chat server that delivers public and private messages.
 */
class DynamicWrite {

  // The server socket.
  private static ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
  // The client socket.
  private static Socket clientSocket = null;

  // This chat server can accept up to maxClientsCount clients' connections.
  private static final int maxClientsCount = 10;
  private static final clientThread[] threads = new clientThread[maxClientsCount];

  static void start(int args) {

    // The default port number.
    int portNumber = 5556;

    TextDemo.textArea.append("Now using port 5556");

    //Make sure the new text is visible, even if there
    //was a selection in the text area.
    TextDemo.textArea.setCaretPosition(TextDemo.textArea.getDocument().getLength());

    /*
     * Open a server socket on the portNumber (default 2222). Note that we can
     * not choose a port less than 1023 if we are not privileged users (root).
     */
    try {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }

    /*
     * Create a client socket for each connection and pass it to a new client
     * thread.
     */
    while (true) {
      try {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
          if (threads[i] == null) {
            (threads[i] = new clientThread(clientSocket, threads)).start();
            break;
          }
        }
        if (i == maxClientsCount) {
          PrintStream os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
          os.println("Server too busy. Try later.");
          os.close();
          clientSocket.close();
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }
    }
  }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TextDemo extends JPanel {
    static JTextArea textArea;
    final static String newline = "\n";

    public TextDemo() {
        super(new GridBagLayout());

        textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        //Add Components to this panel.
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        add(scrollPane, c);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(panel);

        JButton btnTest = new JButton("Test");
        btnTest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textArea.append("Yuup" + newline);

                //Make sure the new text is visible, even if there
                //was a selection in the text area.
                textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
            }
        });
        panel.add(btnTest);
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event dispatch thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Add contents to the window.
        frame.getContentPane().add(new TextDemo());

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
        DynamicWrite.start(5556);
    }
}
```

So there it is. I get thrown a

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DynamicWrite.start(TextDemo.java:203)
    at TextDemo.main(TextDemo.java:311)"
```

whenever I try to run it.
And I cannot for the life of me find the issue.
I know I have a lot to learn.
Thanks,
~P

Comment: Sounds like it's time to hit the debugger.  You could help us out by supply more details, like `TextDemo` for example.  Beware, `static` is not your friend and is often a good sign of bad design...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you forgot to initialize a variable since that is the usual case for null pointer exception. A quick look at your code and I think it is under `TextDemo`. Probably would have been `static JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();`.

Comment: How did you...!? I just deleted that a while ago, not knowing the consequences. I thought I was done with that variable.
Well now the null pointer is gone, but I'm faced with another problem.
The characters I intended to print to the text area aren't printed.

Comment: Because I faced the same problem so many times it stuck in my head. I can't help with your new problem, though, since I am less familiar with it. Mark this as answer to close the question. Thanks.

Comment: I will soon, I'm still getting helpful info out of TomJ ;)

Comment: @Phixle I read that you have C++ background. Java needs variable initialization unlike C++. just putting `JTextArea textArea` won't create an object instance. This was a problem I found when I started on C++.

Comment: @Phixle I kind of fix the bug you are talking about although I don't know how it works. Try create `TextDemo` object in `DynamicWrite` so the line  `TextDemo.textArea.append("Now using port 5556");` will be `TextDemo test = new TextDemo();
test.textArea.append("Now using port 5556");` It works in my comp but don't ask me why it works. I assume because you are not referencing the same `JPanel` and yeah, not recommended to use `static` for the `TextArea`.

Comment: I'm not at my computer right now but that looks like it should work. I'm just questioning whether creating a new TextDemo() would be reasonable. (I know that statement may not make any sense...)
Could you also explain why TextDemo is being used as a variable type? I don't quite understand that...

Comment: Yes, `new TextDemo()` is reasonable since it is a class and your server or the main application that runs the server should create and instance of `JFrame`. TextDemo is a variable type since it is a class. I think it would be great if you could look at Java Swing since it seems your `TextDemo` class has a flawed design, though I am unsure of best practices.

Comment: Actually I am using Swing currently, but needed to take a code sample from the internet to deal with my lack of GUI knowledge. That's where I got the box where the "Yuup" is outputted. As for my other problems,  I believe some multithreading will fix my issues. Thanks.
(Oh and what was flawed in the design of the TextDemo? I might as well fix it.)

Comment: Well, I got it working as I wanted to. Not sure how.
Got a separate thread for updating the text box... Well really I just put a few things in separate threads, but I'm pretty sure that's what did it. Now I just have to learn more in Java so I can improve on this program. Thanks to all who have helped, ~P

Comment: @Phixle The flawed design is that the parent of all Java Swing is JFrame. Creating JFrame from a class inherited from JPanel is not that good - it's like you are creating the mother from the child. That' my personal opinion, though.

Answer (score 0):

Check this portion.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void run() {
    int maxClientsCount = this.maxClientsCount;
    clientThread[] threads = this.threads;
```

You have already declared this 2. Try using another name for this 2 or avoid the 'int' and 'clientThread[]'. Check this and tell me whether it worked.

Comment: Are you using any IDE like NetBeans or Eclipse ?

Comment: Eclipse actually.
And since I just started java yesterday, you're going to have to explain to me what you mean in your answer by "this 2."

Comment: Ok.. I am using NetBeans. I ran your code and a window appeared with a button named Test. When I clicked on it Yuup is displayed below. Is that that the way you supposed it to work ?

Comment: Yes... Except (see I come from a moderate C++ background) I guess I'm trying to use "DynamicWrite.start(5556);" as a function call to the "start(int args)" function. Doesn't seem to be going that way.

Comment: *Whoosh* That just flew over my head. Divided the 2 classes? Into what? And what is this directory you speak of...?
(Sorry. Like I said. *NOOB COMING THROUGH HERE*)

Comment: What I did to your code is, I divided the 2 classes and saved both under the same package. Then I ran one of them and it worked. But the NullpointerException was appearing.

Comment: Oh... So you put the classes in a package and ran the one that referred to the other?

Comment: Yes. Now I divided the 3 classes and saved it as 3 different files under the same package. Still its working and the nullpointerexception is gone and a new exception came..But its working.

Comment: So... What is working? I'm going for the start of a server, not only a working button. ;)
EDIT: I'm gonna hit the hay. Late night, here. Thanks for the help and I'll comment back here tomorrow if I have more questions. Thanks again, ~P.

Comment: I said about the button, not about the server.